# How to connect a Jupyter Notebook to a Spyder kernel?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

The answer to the related post [How to connect to an existing Jupyter Notebook kernel and inspect variables using the Variable explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55451965/how-to-connect-to-an-existing-jupyter-notebook-kernel-and-inspect-variables-usin) seems to be that it's just **not possible**. But what if we try to connect a Jupyter Notebook to a spyder kernel? Could it then be possible to have the kernel available to the Jupyter Notebook, Spyder *and* the Variable explorer in Spyder?

The article [Connecting Spyder IDE to a remote IPython kernel](https://medium.com/@halmubarak/connecting-spyder-ide-to-a-remote-ipython-kernel-25a322f2b2be) makes it sound somewhat possible:

> Doing data science in Jupyter notebook is fun but sometimes you need
>   the ability to poke into variables using the handy variable explorer
>   in Spyder.
>
> Connecting Spyder to a remote kernel is as straightforward as the
>   notebooks. I will walk you through the process.

But I'm not able to reproduce the example, and I'm a bit afraid that I haven't quite understood the authors meaning with the whole article.

---

This is what I've tried:

---

**1.** `conda install spyder-kernels` works fine.

**2.** The same does `python -m spyder_kernels.console` :

[image]

But I'm having problems with the rest, and the article says nothing about connecting Jupyter Notebook to `--existing kernel-19909.json`. I'm also having problems with the part `python -m spyder_kernels.console — matplotlib=’inline’ — ip=x.x.x.x -f=./remotemachine.json`.

Any suggestions as to how I can take this further?

**System info:**

```
The version of the notebook server is: 5.6.0
CPython 3.7.0
IPython 6.5.0
compiler   : MSC v.1912 64 bit (AMD64)
system     : Windows
release    : 7
machine    : AMD64
CPU cores  : 8
interpreter: 64bit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, you would like to connect IPython kernel to Spyder on your local machine. The article you mentioned describes this process for a remote connection, and I believe this was the part that confused you. First, ensure that you updated your `Spyder` to version 3.3.3 or newer as there used to be [a bug that prevented users from seeing their variables in the explorer](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/8582). These are the steps to proceed with the connection:

1. Run `python -m spyder_kernels.console` and note the name of the JSON file that appears in the console output: `To connect another client to this kernel, use: --existing`**`kernel-pid.json`**.
2. Open `Spyder`.
3. Click on `Consoles` in the menu bar and select `Connect to an existing kernel` from the dropdown menu.
4. In the window that opens, enter the previously noted `kernel-pid.json` in the `Connection file` prompt and click `OK`.

After completing these steps, a new console window with the loaded kernel will appear. You can now use it along with the `Variable explorer`.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I've tried your approach a few times, but it does not seem to work on my end. Also, I don't understand how it *should* work. If  `python -m spyder_kernels.console` is the first step, and the next step is to open Spyder, then there's no involvment of a Jupyter Notebook here? Please enlighten med if there's something I'm missing here.

Comment: I've finally realized that although both Jupyter and Spyder are mentioned in the article [Connecting Spyder IDE to a remote IPython kernel](https://medium.com/@halmubarak/connecting-spyder-ide-to-a-remote-ipython-kernel-25a322f2b2be), the connection between the two has got *nothing* to do with eachother. The author only really shows that whats possible to do in jupyter, is also possible to do in Spyder.

Comment: Although you *can* connect Spyder to a running notebook kernel, the variables will not be available for inspection in Spyders variable explorer.

Comment: Any feedback or new info on this? As it stands, your question does not answer the question. But I *really* want to give you the bounty points.

Comment: I believe the latter part of your question was an XY problem. I haven't noticed that earlier and I attempted to help you understand the article you linked to reach the solution. Later, I tried to connect a running Jupyter notebook kernel to Spider and I think it is not possible to inspect such variables in the explorer. I disagree that my response does not answer the question at least partially, but I understand if you choose not to accept it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! The article is just there to provide a possible way to connect Jupyter to a Spyder kernel. In your opinion, have you answered that question? Don't worry about the points though. If you are the only one to answer then you'll get the bounty.

Comment: The final question you asked is "Any suggestions as to how I can take this further?" in reference to your attempt of following the procedure noted in the linked article. I provided the answer to that question.