# How to combine the use of Atom and Anaconda, or connect Atom to a running Jupyter kernel?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, atom-editor

I'd like to add Atom and the package [Hydrogen and the Data Explorer](https://github.com/BenRussert/data-explorer) to my existing Anaconda based Python workflow without messing anything up.

---

Is there a way to connect Atom to my Anaconda installation? I've tried the approaches descripbed in the related post [Using anaconda environment in Atom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43207427/using-anaconda-environment-in-atom) without any success. Or, for testing purposes at least, can I connect Atom to a running Jupyter Notebook kernel like I can with for example Spyder as described in the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55451965/how-to-connect-to-an-existing-jupyter-notebook-kernel-and-inspect-variables-usin)?

**System:**

```
Anaconda   : 5.3.1
Atom       : 1.36.0

compiler   : MSC v.1912 64 bit (AMD64)
system     : Windows
release    : 7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the Hydrogen package into Atom and run your code using Hydrogen. This gives all the power of Jupyter kernels, inside atom. The [Hydrogen package](https://atom.io/packages/search?q=hydrogen) can be downloaded and installed. Then when you have your python script you can go to the Packages menu item and use the Hydrogen selection to run your code. If you have graphics in your script you may have to run it twice to see graphics.